# Winrt triggers and Gridview ItemClick event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrttriggers

I am having trouble and don't know what to pass as command parameter.

```
<triggers:Interactions.Triggers>
    <triggers:EventTrigger EventName="ItemClick">
        <triggers:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter=""/>
    </triggers:EventTrigger>
</triggers:Interactions.Triggers>
```

This is inside gridview declaration. I want to recieve gridview clicked item in binded delegate as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `PassEventArgsToCommand` property of the `InvokeCommandAction` to `true` which will allow to pass `ItemClickEventArgs` pp to your command.

```
<triggers:InvokeCommandAction
           Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

or see [this](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/how-to-bind-the-itemclick-event-to-a-command-and-pass-the-clicked-item-to-it/) article which provides more reliable solution from view point of better design.

Comment: Now another problem arises, my viewmodel is a PCL so itemclickeventargs isnot accessible there.